# How to demangle a C++ name in clang (or gcc)?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, abi

I'm trying to write a quick-and-dirty demangler for clang. I've found a [piece of code](http://squigglybrackets.me/2013/02/11/demangling-type-names-in-clang/) that uses `abi::__cxa_demangle`, but I can't figure out which header it requires. The obvious choice is [ABI.h](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ABI_8h.html) but:

```
demangle.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'ABI.h' file not found
#include <ABI.h>
         ^
```

What do I need to use `abi::__cxa_demangle`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include `cxxabi.h`. In Ubuntu 13 this header is in `/usr/include/c++/4.x` where `x` is minor gcc version.

Comment: This is not part of my linux distribution and not part of the llvm C++ standard library. So what shall I do? There is a `cxxabi.h` in the gcc include path, but will be work with `clang++ -stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: @Walter try `#include <cxxabi.h>` without adding any special include paths. BTW, see if `c++filt` is enough for your needs.

Comment: @Adam that (`#include <cxxabi.h>`) is what I did. No, `c++filt` is not enough for my needs :-((

Comment: @Walter I don't know then. Clang includes it on OSX, so I don't see why it wouldn't be available through some package. I don't think you can assume that you can use gcc's.

Comment: @Walter do you have `libstdc++-4.8-dev` or `libc++-dev` (or the equivalent on your distribution for your compiler) installed?

Answer (score 1):

Include cxxabi.h, but for clang on Ubuntu you'll need to install the package libc++abi-dev.